# Alert component from Material UI not showing up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, alert

Hey there was polishing my app since I finally finish it and I though it would be better looking to replace all the `window.alerts` for Alerts from MUI (cause they look waaaay better) however it doesn't seem to be showing up for some reason ?

So for example I have that when the passwords doesn't match it sends a message:

```
const register = (e) => {
        if(password !== confirmsPassword){
            alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden");
        }

        else if(password.length < 6){
            alert("Su contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres");
        }

        else{
          //Some smart and long code that updates the information to the firebase
        }
        
    }
```

And that works it pops the following:

[image]

However when I try to use Alerts from MUI:

```
const register = (e) => {
        if(password !== confirmsPassword){
            <Alert severity="error">Las contraseñas no coinciden</Alert>
        }

        else if(password.length < 6){
            <Alert severity="error">Su contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres</Alert>
        }

        else{
              //Some smart and long code that updates the information to the firebase
        }
        
    }
```

it doesn't do anything at all no message no alert no nothing. This is the [Alert](https://mui.com/components/alert/) MUI link

Answer (score 2):

MUI based answer.

So after a few attempts I found a solution using MUI components and is a mix between Alerts, Snackbar, MuiAlert components

So basically make another component, for this example it will be InstantMessage.js

```
import React, {useState, forwardRef} from 'react'
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

const InstantMessage = ({message}) =>  {
    
        const [open, setOpen] = useState(true); 
        //Leave this true since we are not using a button
    
        const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
            if (reason === 'clickaway') {
              return;
            }
        
            setOpen(false);
          };

    return (
        <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
            <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="error">{message}</Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    )
}

export default InstantMessage
```

And then in the component you want to use the alerts:

```
//Initialize you can call it alerts or w/e you want
//I'll use error cause I only catch errors in this piece of code.
    import InstantMessage from './InstantMessage ';

    const [error, setError] = useState(false); //Controls Alert
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('') //Controls Message
    
    so for example I have a register function with firebase:
    
    const register = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((auth) => {
                    if(auth.user){
                      //Some smart code
                    }
                }).catch((e) => 
                {
                    if(e.message === "Some error example"){
                        setMessage("some alert")
                        setError(true); // Turn On Alert so it displays
                    }
            });
            
            setError(false); //very important to set this back to off
        }
```

Finally somewhere in your render/return add the following statement:

```
//if error then call component InstantMessage and send the prop message
{error ?  <InstantMessage message = {message} /> : `` }
```

In the end it should look like this:

[image]